# How do you round a number in JavaScript in a base other than 10?

Tags: javascript, rounding, radix

For example, let's say I have the number `12.24` in base 8 (`10.3125` in base 10), and I want to round the number to 1 point of precision so that I get `12.3`.

Comment: There's definitely no built-in way to do this. I would try capturing `n` digits after the decimal point and then checking if the `n+1`th digit is 4, 5, 6, or 7 to conditionally increase the previous digit. (Or, higher than `Math.ceil(B/2)` for base `B` in general? I don't know how to handle odd bases.) Don't use any numeric operations (other than on a digit level to compare and increment), since you're just doing a string-to-string transformation.

Comment: Throwing in an idea: Can't base 8 be represented accurately in base 2? 12.24 being 001 010 . 010 100? If yes, one can look at the last bits, if > 100, add 1000. Either way clear the last three bit.

Comment: `((10.3125 * 32) & 7) > 4 ?
    ((10.3125 * 8) >> 0) / 8 + 16
   :((10.3215 * 8) >> 0) / 8`

Comment: doesn't 12.24 round to 12.2??

Comment: @TheBombSquad No - don't forget it's base 8

Comment: o.. yea fr.. hmmm that's what he means eh.. wait but.. yea im confused pls explain y .3 and not .2  ;-; @Bergi

Comment: *"I want to round the number to 1 decimal place"*: well, if it is an octal representation, then that 1 position is not a *decimal* place...

Comment: You could be really sophisticated and implement base 8 banker's rounding, so that 12.24 would round to 12.2 but 12.34 would round to 12.4.

Comment: @TheBombSquad Just like in decimal rounding (assuming [half up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) or [commercial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) rounding), where the digits followed by 0 1 2 3 4 are truncated and digits followed by 5 6 7 8 9 are incremented, in octal it's 0 1 2 3 that round down and 4 5 6 7 that round up. 12.24 is right in the middle between 12.20 and 12.30.

Comment: @trincot lol, very true. I have updated the question to be more accurate. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

- There isn´t a function in js that can do this. So need to create one in order to do it. What it does is to check if the digit to fix (in your case the "4") is closer to the base (8) or closer to 0:

  ```
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
  ```

Then, just add or substract the difference to 10 or 0, so if the number is `12.24`, it would return:

```
return 12.24 + 0.06;   // ---> equals to 12.3
```

If the number is  `12.23`, returns:

```
return 12.23 - 0.03    // ---> equals to 12.2
```

So could make something like this:

```
function round(n, base, precision) {
  const digit_tofix = n.toString().split(".")[1].split("")[precision];
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
    return (n + (10 - digit_tofix) / Math.pow(10, precision + 1)).toFixed(precision);
  }else {
    return (n - digit_tofix / Math.pow(10, precision + 1)).toFixed(precision);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** however, this wouldn´t catch *carry overflow*. So a number in **base_8** like this:

```
55.74
```

would transform in:

```
55.74 + 0.06 = 55.8   // --> number 8 doesn´t exist in octal
```

So there must be an *overflow-check* loop using `do while()`. What this statement do is to move the `digit_tofix` to the previous number and check if there is an overflow every time we make an addition:

```
// Overflow check
do {
    n += (10 - digit_tofix) / Math.pow(10, precision + 1);
    precision--;
    digit_tofix = precision > -1 ? n.toFixed(precision + 1).split(".")[1].split("")[precision] :
                                   n.toFixed(0).split(".")[0].split("")[precision + n.toString().split(".")[0].split("").length];
} while(digit_tofix == base);
    
return n.toFixed(precision > -1 ? precision + 1 : 0);
```

- It works for any base up to 10 (not hexadecimal since contains letters) and any precision you want, just changing the parameters in the `round()` function. Here some working examples

#### Octal

```js
const oct = 12.24;

console.log( round(oct, 8, 1) );

function round(n, base, precision) {
  let digit_tofix = n.toString().split(".")[1].split("")[precision];
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
    // Overflow check
    do {
        n += (10 - digit_tofix) / Math.pow(10, precision + 1);
        precision--;
        digit_tofix = precision > -1 ? n.toFixed(precision + 1).split(".")[1].split("")[precision] :
                                       n.toFixed(0).split(".")[0].split("")[precision + n.toString().split(".")[0].split("").length];
    } while(digit_tofix == base);
    return n.toFixed(precision > -1 ? precision + 1 : 0);
  }else {
    return (n - digit_tofix / Math.pow(10, precision + 1)).toFixed(precision);
  }
}
```

#### Binary

```js
const bin = 10011.011;

console.log( round(bin, 2, 1) );

function round(n, base, precision) {
  let digit_tofix = n.toString().split(".")[1].split("")[precision];
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
    // Overflow check
    do {
        n += (10 - digit_tofix) / Math.pow(10, precision + 1);
        precision--;
        digit_tofix = precision > -1 ? n.toFixed(precision + 1).split(".")[1].split("")[precision] :
                                       n.toFixed(0).split(".")[0].split("")[precision + n.toString().split(".")[0].split("").length];
    } while(digit_tofix == base);
    return n.toFixed(precision > -1 ? precision + 1 : 0);
  }else {
    return (n - digit_tofix / Math.pow(10, precision + 1)).toFixed(precision);
  }
}
```

---

## Solution 2

```
function round(n, base, precision) {
  // To get number value of letter: a = 10, b = 11, c = 12 ...
  const getNumber = e => isNaN(e) ? e.charCodeAt(0) - 87 : parseInt(e);

  // Just to check incompability and invalid parameters
  const checkIncompatible = () => {
    if (digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) > 1 || 
        (digits.some(d => isNaN(d) && (getNumber(d) < 10 || getNumber(d) > 35) && d != ".")))   return "Invalid Number";
    if (digits.some(d => getNumber(d) >= base  && d != "."))    return "Number doesn´t match base";
    if (precision < 0)  return "Invalid precision argument";
    if (base < 2 || base > 36)  return "Invalid base argument";
    return false;
  };
  
  // Recursive function to carry overflow
  const add = p => {
    if (digits[p] == ".") add(p - 1);
    else if (getNumber(digits[p]) + 1 == base) {
      digits[p] = "0";
      if (p > 0)    add(p - 1);
      else digits.unshift("1");
    }else {
      if (isNaN(digits[p])) digits[p] = String.fromCharCode(digits[p].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      else digits[p] = digits[p] < 9 ? parseInt(digits[p]) + 1 : "a" ;
    }
  };
  
  n = n.toString().toLowerCase().split(",").join(".");  // In case there is a comma
  let digits = n.split("");

  // Avoid problems with undefined array index and other issues
  if (typeof digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision] === "undefined" ||
      digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) < 1)   return n;
  let state = checkIncompatible();
  if (state) return state;

  const digit_tofix = getNumber(digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision]);

  // Check if digit_tofix is closer to base or zero
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
   add(digits.indexOf(".") + precision);
  }

  // Splice the array to get the substring
  digits.splice(digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision);
  if (!precision) digits.splice(-1);
  return digits.join("");
}
```

This solution is more complex, but is broader since you can use any number **from base 2 to 36**, it means you can use hexadecimal.

Similarly to first solution, it checks if the digit to fix (in your case the "4") is closer to the base (8) or closer to 0:

```
if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
```

If is closer to **zero**, just need to take the substring of the number (using `splice()` array method). So if number is:

```
"12.23"
```

its substring is

```
"12.2"
```

But if digit-to-fix is closer to the **base**, we need to add **+1** to the previous number, so if number is:

```
"12.24"
```

its substring is

```
"12.3"    //--> 2 + 1 = 3
```

### Special cases

For example, if number in **base_8** is:

```
"12.74"
```

its substring should be

```
"13.0"    // 7 + 1 = 8 (base is 8 so there is an overflow)
```

That´s why there is a recursive function called `add()` in order to carry in case of overflow.

The `round()` function returns a string with the new number.

### *Try the solution*

#### Hexadecimal

```js
console.log( round("c3.bf9", 16, 2) );
console.log( round("AA.D1", 16, 1) );
console.log( round("ff.fff", 16, 0) );

function round(n, base, precision) {
    const getNumber = e => isNaN(e) ? e.charCodeAt(0) - 87 : parseInt(e);
  const checkIncompatible = () => {
    if (digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) > 1 || 
        (digits.some(d => isNaN(d) && (getNumber(d) < 10 || getNumber(d) > 35) && d != ".")))   return "Invalid Number";
    if (digits.some(d => getNumber(d) >= base  && d != "."))    return "Number doesn´t match base";
    if (precision < 0)  return "Invalid precision argument";
    if (base < 2 || base > 36)  return "Invalid base argument";
    return false;
  };
  
  const add = p => {
    if (digits[p] == ".") add(p - 1);
    else if (getNumber(digits[p]) + 1 == base) {
      digits[p] = "0";
      if (p > 0)    add(p - 1);
      else digits.unshift("1");
    }else {
      if (isNaN(digits[p])) digits[p] = String.fromCharCode(digits[p].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      else digits[p] = digits[p] < 9 ? parseInt(digits[p]) + 1 : "a" ;
    }
  };
  
  n = n.toString().toLowerCase().split(",").join(".");
  let digits = n.split("");
  if (typeof digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision] === "undefined" ||
      digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) < 1)   return n;
  let state = checkIncompatible();
  if (state) return state;
  const digit_tofix = getNumber(digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision]);
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
   add(digits.indexOf(".") + precision);
  }
  digits.splice(digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision);
  if (!precision) digits.splice(-1);
  return digits.join("");
}
```

#### Octal

```js
console.log( round(12.24, 8, 1) );
console.log( round(17.77, 8, 1) );
console.log( round(0.74, 8, 1) );

function round(n, base, precision) {
    const getNumber = e => isNaN(e) ? e.charCodeAt(0) - 87 : parseInt(e);
  const checkIncompatible = () => {
    if (digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) > 1 || 
        (digits.some(d => isNaN(d) && (getNumber(d) < 10 || getNumber(d) > 35) && d != ".")))   return "Invalid Number";
    if (digits.some(d => getNumber(d) >= base  && d != "."))    return "Number doesn´t match base";
    if (precision < 0)  return "Invalid precision argument";
    if (base < 2 || base > 36)  return "Invalid base argument";
    return false;
  };
  
  const add = p => {
    if (digits[p] == ".") add(p - 1);
    else if (getNumber(digits[p]) + 1 == base) {
      digits[p] = "0";
      if (p > 0)    add(p - 1);
      else digits.unshift("1");
    }else {
      if (isNaN(digits[p])) digits[p] = String.fromCharCode(digits[p].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      else digits[p] = digits[p] < 9 ? parseInt(digits[p]) + 1 : "a" ;
    }
  };
  
  n = n.toString().toLowerCase().split(",").join(".");
  let digits = n.split("");
  if (typeof digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision] === "undefined" ||
      digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) < 1)   return n;
  let state = checkIncompatible();
  if (state) return state;
  const digit_tofix = getNumber(digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision]);
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
   add(digits.indexOf(".") + precision);
  }
  digits.splice(digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision);
  if (!precision) digits.splice(-1);
  return digits.join("");
}
```

#### Binary

```js
console.log( round(101.10, 2, 1) );
console.log( round("100,11", 2, 1) );
console.log( round(100.11, 2, 1) );

function round(n, base, precision) {
    const getNumber = e => isNaN(e) ? e.charCodeAt(0) - 87 : parseInt(e);
  const checkIncompatible = () => {
    if (digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) > 1 || 
        (digits.some(d => isNaN(d) && (getNumber(d) < 10 || getNumber(d) > 35) && d != ".")))   return "Invalid Number";
    if (digits.some(d => getNumber(d) >= base  && d != "."))    return "Number doesn´t match base";
    if (precision < 0)  return "Invalid precision argument";
    if (base < 2 || base > 36)  return "Invalid base argument";
    return false;
  };
  
  const add = p => {
    if (digits[p] == ".") add(p - 1);
    else if (getNumber(digits[p]) + 1 == base) {
      digits[p] = "0";
      if (p > 0)    add(p - 1);
      else digits.unshift("1");
    }else {
      if (isNaN(digits[p])) digits[p] = String.fromCharCode(digits[p].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      else digits[p] = digits[p] < 9 ? parseInt(digits[p]) + 1 : "a" ;
    }
  };
  
  n = n.toString().toLowerCase().split(",").join(".");
  let digits = n.split("");
  if (typeof digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision] === "undefined" ||
      digits.reduce((a, d) => d == "." ? ++a : a, 0) < 1)   return n;
  let state = checkIncompatible();
  if (state) return state;
  const digit_tofix = getNumber(digits[digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision]);
  if (base - digit_tofix <= base / 2) {
   add(digits.indexOf(".") + precision);
  }
  digits.splice(digits.indexOf(".") + 1 + precision);
  if (!precision) digits.splice(-1);
  return digits.join("");
}
```